# Create a JavaScript program, that has an array of strings and the program sorts in O(nlog n) time

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to create a JavaScript program, that has an array of strings which also  sorts in O(nlog n) time.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: `['str','str2'].sort()`

Answer (score 0):

First up define what sorting algorithm you are going to use. There are hundreds out there, but only a few really good. You need to look specifically to `O(n log n)`  algorithms.

`O(n log n)` algorithms are also called loglinear algorithms, depending on your usecase you should use a different algorithm.

Heapsort or mergesort are the most widely known loglinear algorithms. 
Heapsort is the best for selection.
Mergesort is the best for merging.
So what type of sort are you going to do?

Then when you have defined the algorithm build you code. First make two arrays and fill them with random data. Then write the javascript implementation of the sorting algorithm you are going to use.

Better do your homework yourself, its to learn from it.

---

Links:
[Wikipedia Sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) 
[javascript merge sort](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/10/02/computer-science-and-javascript-merge-sort/)
[javascript heap sort](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/appendix2.html)
[java heapsort but excellent reading material](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/11/algorithm-heapsort.html)
[again java mergesort but excellent reading material](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/11/algorithm-merge-sort.html)